# How can I electronically measure the load of an AC transformer?

Tags: transformer, ac, electronic-load

I'm wondering how to electronically measure the load of an AC transformer at the output of the secondary winding. I don't want to calculate the core size but use a measurement instrument - which one? I have an electronic DC load meter available, and I'm wondering if I can measure the transformer's power in "continuous power" (CP) mode? In other words, can I measure the power of an AC transformer using an electronic load designed for DC current measurement?

Comment: Precisely what parameters of the powered load are you wanting to measure?

Comment: @Andyaka wattage or amps is enough for me. Let's say, I want to identify an unknown power transformer - I don't know how much current I could get. Connecting bulbs or power resistors until transformer will get hot is not an elegant way and a bit of random. I would love to just measure it with an instrument.

Comment: I'm afraid temperature rise is *the* indication of power the transformer can handle for a given input (frequency&voltage).